# how to copy from current folder to another folder

Tags: command-line, directory, cp, copy

how to copy between
current directory to another directory
eg. i am trying to copy my current directory i.e Desktop to var/www/html

```
cp form.html ./var/www/html
```

receive a following error

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘./var/www.html’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via

```
cp form.html /var/www/html
```

The dot means, relative to your current folder and you need an absolute path.

If `form.html` isn't a file but a folder, you should add the `-r` switch to copy recursively.

```
cp -r form.html /var/www/html
```

---

More about the `cp` command with `man cp` in a terminal or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp).